# Growth rate of roots vs logarithms

Tags: time-complexity

I'm trying to prove that the tenth root of n grows slower than the logarithms but I have no clue.
Also, how can I find which of two functions grows faster? It it related to derivatives?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: One way to show this is indeed using L'Hopital's rule (10 times, probably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using L'Hôpital's rule:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1/10}}{\log n} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{10} n^{-9/10}}{n^{-1}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1/10}}{10} = +\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much :)